# Carousel stops working as soon as html content is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This carousel that I am using stops working, one could drag / swipe a new slide into view by dragging / swiping the previous slide out, once I add an  tag inside one of the slides.

The css, html, and js that make up the carousel is as follows:

EDIT: I could not replicate the problem in JSFiddle so here are links to a working version without the html content in one slide and the non-working version with.

Working: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/270523/help/carousel/carousel.html

Non-Working: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/270523/help/carousel/carousel2.html

Here is the non-working html:

```
<body>
    <div id="carousel">
        <ul>
            <li class="pane1"><h2>Swipe...</h2><object data="http://stackoverflow.com"><iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com" /></object></li>
            <li class="pane2"><h2>...or drag...</h2></li>
            <li class="pane3"><h2>...or swipe...</h2></li>
            <li class="pane4"><h2>...or drag...</h2></li>
            <li class="pane5"><h2>...or swipe...</h2></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</body>
```

The working html just has text in the first slide instead of the object tag.

Comment: holy code, any chance you can trim this down a bit?  Maybe put a complete example in a fiddle, and then just show the js that is illustrating your issue.

Comment: Would you mind awfully putting that in a jsfiddle with the paths to your js, for example jquery.hammer.min.js that we would have to google to find, and then possibly clarify how to have it working and how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Nix Yes, that was quite a bit of code, apologies. I tried making a fiddle, but I couldn't replicate the issue. So, I posted live examples in the question now. Thank you for being willing to help!

Comment: @popnoodles Instead of a jsfiddle, I have linked to live example of the files with the actual problems in the question. Thank you for being willing to help!

Comment: I would still recommend putting some code in your question, external links often break and as a result reduce the value of your question.

Comment: @Nix Okay, thank you. I just did that.

Comment: Console error: "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://stackoverflow.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console error: "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: stackoverflow.com does not permit cross-origin framing."

I'm guessing that that's breaking the plugin altogether.

Comment: Ah, I was just using stack overflow as an example page. All the real pages to be used will be on my server. Okay, thank you.